# T-SQL - how to swap rows and columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a resultset structure like this

```
ID       Value      Name
1       Oranges     Reponse
1       42      Count
2       Apples      Reponse
2       65      Count
3       Figs        Reponse
3       74      Count
```

and I want to get to this:

```
ID     Response       Count
1       Oranges     42
2       Apples      65
3       Figs        74
```

using SQL.  Is there a way to do this?  thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Value AS [Response], b.Value AS [Count]
FROM your_table AS a
    INNER JOIN your_table AS b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.Name = 'Response'
    AND b.Name = 'Count'
```

Answer (score 6):

this was always such a chore pre sql server 2005.

now i use [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.VALUE RESPONSE, C.VALUE COUNT 
FROM _table  A 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, VALUE, NAME 
  FROM _table 
  WHERE _table.Name = 'Count'
) C ON A.ID = C.ID
WHERE A.NAME='Response' and C.NAME='Count'
```