# how to convert column values into comma seperated row vlaues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with values as

```
FKTABLE_NAME               FKCOLUMN_NAME               PKCOLUMN_NAME
table1                     column1                        column1
table1                     column2                        column2
table2                     column1                        column1
table2                     column2                        column2
```

How I need to convert this into

```
FKTABLE_NAME               FKCOLUMN_NAME               PKCOLUMN_NAME

tablel1                    column1,column2                column1,column2
table12                    column1,column2                column1,column2
```

Basically, I am trying to get the comma seperated columns group by the table name.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working query on any db

```
select distinct table_name,
  stuff((select ','+data_type
   from information_schema.columns b
   where b.table_name=a.table_name
   for xml path(''),type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS data_types,
  stuff((select ','+column_name
   from information_schema.columns b
   where b.table_name=a.table_name
   for xml path(''),type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS column_names
from information_schema.columns a
```

And here is your query

```
select distinct FKTABLE_NAME,
  stuff((select ','+FKCOLUMN_NAME
   from tbl b
   where b.FKTABLE_NAME=a.FKTABLE_NAME
   for xml path(''),type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS FKCOLUMN_NAMES,
  stuff((select ','+PKCOLUMN_NAME
   from tbl b
   where b.FKTABLE_NAME=a.FKTABLE_NAME
   for xml path(''),type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS PKCOLUMN_NAMES
from tbl a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Col1Name] + ',' + [Col2Name] + ',' ... + [ColNName]
FROM [tableName]
```

Comment: I need to convert column values into comma separated values into a single value group by table name

Comment: oh, sorry. You want to [swap rows and columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584232/t-sql-how-to-swap-rows-and-columns)?

Answer (score 0):

As with all string aggregation problems I advise writing a custom aggregate (and I STRONGLY advise using a clr aggregate for best performance) and write a query like this

```
select fktablename, stringAggregate(fkcolumnname), stringAggregate(pkcolumnname)
group by 
fktablename
```

[some tips here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1691)

[other nice reading](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#_Toc205129487)

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL statement is used for converting single column data in a single row:

```
declare @testdata varchar(8000)
set @testdata=''

select @testdata=@testdata+NAME+', ' from User where ID in('1','2','3','4','5')
print @testdata

select substring(@testdata,0,len(@testdata))
```

In above the above example:

- User is a table
- NAME is column of user which data will be manuplate in row
- ID is column of user

For reference see below link:

http://www.devdescent.com/2012/02/column-data-in-to-single-row-with-comma.html