# How can I get one row for each user and concat two row values in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm working with Wordpress and Event Espresso, but generally, I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT m.user_id, m.meta_key, m.meta_value from wp_usermeta as m
WHERE m.meta_key in ('event_espresso_city','event_espresso_state')
ORDER BY m.user_id
```

I'm trying to get the city and state of a user, so I want to group by user_id, but if I do that it will only get the city value and ignore, or overwrite the state value.

Is there a way that I can do a concat(m.metavalue1, m.meta_value2) WHERE m.meta_key in ('event_espresso_city','event_espresso_state')?  That is, it would have to concat two rows...  Any suggestions?

Comment: Join twice to the `wp_usermeta` table. Once for the city and once for the state. FWIW, this type of question has been asked before on this site.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584232/t-sql-how-to-swap-rows-and-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL offers the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function for this purpose.

In a general case, you will have to join the table with itself to produce a single record from multiple records in the same table, like:

```
SELECT m_city.user_id, m_city.meta_value as city, m_state.meta_value as state
FROM wp_usermeta as m_city
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as m_state on m_city.user_id = m_state.user_id
WHERE m_city.meta_key = 'event_espresso_city'
AND m_state.meta_key = 'event_espresso_state'
ORDER BY m_city.user_id
```

Comment: Not sure if it's how I am doing it or not, but LEFT JOIN returned the correct number of entries, where INNER JOIN did not.

Comment: This is perfect, btw.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Select coalesce(c.userId, s.userId) UserId, 
     c.meta_value City, s.meta_Value state
From wp_usermeta c
   full Join wp_usermeta s
       On s.UserId = c.UserId
          and c.meta_key = 'event_espresso_city'
          and s.meta_key = 'event_espresso_state'
Where @userId in (c.User_Id, s.User_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

See my comment on your question to a post that shows an example of using a self inner join to achieve this. Your query would look something like:

```
SELECT ma.user_id, ma.meta_key as City, mb.meta_value as State
FROM wp_usermeta as ma
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as mb
ON ma.user_id = mb.user_id
WHERE 
ma.meta_key = 'event_espresso_city'
AND
mb.meta_key = 'event_espresso_state'
ORDER BY ma.user_id
```

Comment: Not sure if it's how I am doing it or not, but LEFT JOIN returned the correct number of entries, where INNER JOIN did not.